# Php json_encode from mysql > output without column names

Tags: php, mysql, json

this is my code on a php page connected to mysql server.

```
$temp = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($temp);
```

The output is:

```
[{"column1":"1448741941","column2":"951"},{"column1":"1448747281","column2":"862"}]
```

That's is including the column title + data, and i wanna know how can i get only datas, like

```
    [[1448741941,951],[1448747281,862]]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the quick answer, send in an array with the data only:

```
$temp = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp[] = array( $row['column1'], $row['column2'] );
}
echo json_encode($temp);
```

**Edit** You might actually whant this too **JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK**:

```
$temp = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp[] = array( $row['column1'], $row['column2'] );
}
echo json_encode($temp, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Another way is this:

```
    $temp[] = array( 
        intval( $row['column1'] ), 
        intval( $row['column2'] ) );
```

Comment: The output will be with quotes [["1448741941","951"],["1448747281","862"]] :/

Comment: Fixed with JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK